# How does the NPN transistor in a 555 timer discharge the capacitor when the output is low?

Tags: transistors, flipflop, 555, npn

I am new to electronics and I'm trying to understand how the 555 timer works based on the diagram below. I am following the tutorial/explanation at https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html

[image]

In the tutorial, for the description of pin 7 (discharge), it says:

> The discharge pin is connected directly to the Collector of an internal NPN transistor which is used to “discharge” the timing capacitor to ground when the output at pin 3 switches “LOW”

However, I don't understand how the base of the transistor could be allowing the capacitor a path to ground (which would require the base to be "high", if I understand correctly) if the output at pin 3 is "low" at the same time, since they are both connected to /Q. Shouldn't they both be "high" or both be "low"?

Comment: What if the "Output Driver" does an inversion of the /Q? (And shouldn't that be Q as it is not the inverted Flip-flop output?)

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y7rpp9lh    this shows it better although the true schematic at pin 3 is complementary Darlington Emitter followers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OUTPUT DRIVER" in your diagram doesn't show its logical function (which is a logical inversion). Some other internal diagrams of a 555 shown below.
These diagrams are simplifications. There actually **is** a transistor connected to pin 7, but its base drive is not shown properly in these diagrams. This transistor is configured as a switch, which is either non-conducting, or it is "ON", pulling a lot of current from pin 7 to ground (pin 1).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have previously done an LT-Spice simulation of the equivalent circuit of the 555 chip using 2N2904 and 2N3906 transistor models. *(Yes you could even physically build a discrete version of the 555 if you detest the IC in its 8-pin package).*

Here is a waveform from the simulation showing the OUT, DIS and BASE of the DISCHARGE NPN transistor. Note that the BASE is high during the time the OUT pin is low.

[image]

Here is a picture of the simulation schematic. This first part is the connection setup for the 555 model.

[image]

Next I show the schematic portion that is the actual 555 model.

[image]

If you look closely at the output section (which I show a snip of below) you will note that both the Q14 DISCHARGE transistor and the Q24 transistor that pulls the OUT low derive their base drive from the same source.

[image]